# How to print dynamically coming class name and their xpath is same? Using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Here I need to print class"section__form" or "section__blank-slate". Any class those visible. Using selenium web driver.
Case 1:
[image]

Case 2:[image]

```
    <body>
     <div class="main">
       <div class="order-summary-recap">
           <div class="wrap">
                 <div id="checkout" class="current-step-shipping_and_payment_method" data-session-storage="">
                       <div id="contact-information" class="section step step--completed">
                             <div id="shipping-method" class="section step step--current">
                                 <div class="section__header">
                                 <div class="section__form">
                                     <div "shipping-msg">Wait while we fetch available shipping rates…</div>
                                 <div class="section__summary"> </div>
                             </div>
                       </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>   
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for printing the className(attribute name) is quite simple
just locate that element and use

element.getAttribute("class");

This will retrieve the class attribute of your located element.

@Mani
There was some problem with your html(xml) code. I tried to fix that and I could get the below xml

```
   <body>
     <div class="main">
       <div class="order-summary-recap">
           <div class="wrap">
                 <div id="checkout" class="current-step-shipping_and_payment_method" data-session-storage="">
                       <div id="contact-information" class="section step step--completed">
                             <div id="shipping-method" class="section step step--current">
                                 <div class="section__header">
                                 <div class="section__form">
                                     <div class="shipping-msg">Wait while we fetch available shipping rates?</div>
                                 <div class="section__summary"> </div>
                             </div>
                       </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>   
</div>
</div>
 </body>
```

And to get to your element(section__form)

Use x-path :- `//div[@class='section__header']/child::div`

And please let me know, if it works.

Comment: how i locate the element, even these classes come dynamically, depend what user give input to the form

Comment: We can use the x-path as locator type for dynamic pages!!
And there will be least situations, where the classname will be dynamic as it will impact the field's functionality.
And, here, I am just trying to write some sort of genric x-path for 2nd div under div of "shipping method"
//div[contains(@id,'shipping-method')]/div[2]
or
use descendant xpath axes instead of div[2]

Comment: Well xpath of the both classes is same"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]" 
Now how i get the class name: "section__form" and "section__blank-slate" using the xpath

Comment: Hello @Anil Chandna please

Comment: @Mani, in my above comment, i have mentioned the xpath of your object. The xpatj provided by you is absolute.please try to make this a bit generic by using relative xpath

Comment: for later i will user the generic xpath, but please, how i get the Only class name using this xpath.

Comment: Dude!!!!
For getting x-path, you do not need to involve the same class name.
Get any of the element nearby your target element and then use x-path axes (siblings/descendant etc )

Comment: Well, i have to implement the condition those are based on the these two classes only. So i need to print the class name only. If class name print, then i apply the condition based on the class name.

Comment: I think, there is some sort of communication gap b/w us!!
I also said the same thing.
Locate your required div element(use some reference element and take help of x-path axes). And after locating that element , get the attribute.
if you face problem in this
Send me a static page of this html
I will address this problem

Comment: Well i use your given solution, but this will print the text those on the second div, not the class name."section__form" or "section__blank-slate"

Comment: I have added the code on my question. 
Now  i want to print the class name"section__form"
But in-place of class name, text "Wait while we fetch available shipping rates…" is print on the Console.

Comment: No, @Anil Chandna this will not work for me. 
Now on this case nothing is print on the console

Comment: Can you please post your webdriver code snippet here ?

Comment: Yes, can i give you the  website link or code
Site link: http://testing-671.myshopify.com/
Front-end password: testing
This is testing site and we perform some part on this only before doing on the live as (development purpose)

Comment: Process, add product to cart and go to checkout page via cart
follow the process of the checkout, after adding shipping address then shipping rate are calculated.